# how to make a runnable jar file in eclipse which is open in double click?

Tags: jar

I make a java desktop application. But it is not open in mouse double click. What is the processes of making runnable jar file Which file i Double click and open. I read many blog as like ==> http://hackpchack.blogspot.com/2014/01/how-to-make-runnable-jar-file-in-eclipse.html  but i can not able to run by double click. What is the actual method to make runnable jar file. 
please somebody help me ...

Comment: Interesting . what does you main method contains?

Comment: method means procedures

Comment: yes main method,behaviour,procedure,function ?

Comment: Look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html specifically http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html